# loading json data into button that expands - bootstrap 4 beta

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hi I'm trying to format and plug in some data from a `js` document, formatted as javascript objects, into a div within a collapsed `div`, which expands when you click a button.
I'm using leaflet and working with the exact same data, and I've had no problem plugging the json data into map popups.
`jquery append` isn't working at all, even if I just try to append text nothing shows up.
I've tried about 10 different solutions from a bunch of different questions, but still nothing will show up.
I am using bootstrap 4 beta.

latest js attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){

        $('#everydayFoodContent').append('<p>hello!</p>');
    });    
});
```

I've also tried just having

```
$('#everydayFoodContent').append('<p>hello!</p>');
```

on its own but that still doesn't work.
I've also tried this:

```
$everydayFoodContent=$('#everydayFoodContent');
$everydayFoodContent.append('<p>hello!</p>');
```

I've also tried using "`console.log('#everydayFoodContent');`" as I've seen other answers to similar questions suggest this to check and make sure the div is available(I think) but honestly I don't know what the purpose of `console.log` is or what I'm supposed to see if it does or doesn't work, and haven't been able to find anything online that concisely explains this. When I include it, nothing related to this div shows up in the console, if that's helpful.

here's the html:

```
<button class="btn btn-light" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#everydaycollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="everydaycollapse">
  Everyday</button> 
<div class="collapse" id="everydaycollapse">
  <div class="card card-block" id="everydayContent">
      <div id="everdayFoodContent">Food</div><br><br>
      <div id="everdayDrinkContent">Drink</div>
  </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a simple spelling error.  You spelled the ID of the div in question "**everday**FoodContent", and you're trying to append it with the id "**everyday**FoodContent" in the jQuery call.  *Note the 'y'.*

Changing your append to this will resolve the issue:

```
 $('#everdayFoodContent').append('<p>hello!</p>');
```

Or, alternately, you can revise your div ID to have the correct spelling like so:

```
<div id="everydayFoodContent">Food</div><br><br>
```

Suppose you just need to decide on how you want to spell it! ;)

**EDIT**

I've attached the full code of both the working HTML and CSS, so perhaps it will be easier.  Copy and paste these into your project.  If it works, then there was some other syntax mistake in your code.  If not, then you may be loading jQuery into your file incorrectly.

**HTML**

```
<button  class="btn btn-light" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#everydaycollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="everydaycollapse">Everyday</button> 
<div class="collapse" id="everydaycollapse">
    <div class="card card-block" id="everydayContent">
        <div id="everydayFoodContent">Food</div><br><br>
        <div id="everdayDrinkContent">Drink</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        console.log("button clicked");
        $('#everydayFoodContent').append('<p>hello!</p>');
    });    
})
```

I've verified that this code will successfully append the string whenever the button is clicked.  It really should work in your browser.  If not, it's probably going to be a missing dependency or something else on your environment.

Comment: oh my gosh, I got so excited when I read this that it was such a simple fix! but, I changed the spelling of the ID to be "everydayFoodContent", and tried to append with all the methods listed in my question, but it's still not working :(

Comment: Hmm, that's odd.  I loaded it up in my browser and was able to get the text appending, no problem..

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the spellings of both the ID and the jQuery call are the same? @Ailis

Comment: @Ailis Also, check your browser console and be sure that jQuery is loaded in correctly.  If jQuery isn't there, then it's not going to be able to make the call.  If you have any errors you may want to investigate them.

Comment: yes, I just copied the ID from the div & pasted it into the jquery call to make sure, and still nothing appears.

Comment: @Ailis if you don't mind, please load your entire HTML document into your post so we can better see what's going on.  Or upload it to something like jFiddle if it's a hefty file.

Comment: @Ailis and you saved and refreshed the page after doing so?

Comment: @Ailis, see my edits, that code should work fine.  Tested on my end and all works fine.  If it's still not working as expected, it likely has something to do with you not setting up something right, perhaps missing jQuery or you're not containing a reference to your main JavaScript file in your HTML.